# TSOP382838 IR receiver keeps outputting signal even if no infrared light is present

Tags: led, infrared, light

This is a beginner question.

This is my first time using an ir receiver. The one I have is a TSOP38238. I have setup a simple circuit that consists of a visible led and receiver. When I have no infrared light pointing to it, the led keeps blinking. Shown in the 3 second gif below.

[image: LED keeps blinking even when no IR light is pointing to the receiver]
<sub>(source: [ezgif.com](http://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-284553978.gif))</sub>

I am powering the receiver with a 5v dc source. When I point infrared light at it, the led blinks like it should be.

Why is this happenning? Does it mean there is infrared light at 38khz around me? Is this suppossed to happen naturally? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Although I have no experience with this particular IR receiver I have not seen this effect with similar devices. The LED and receiver are very close, can it be that you have a feedback loop where the IR receiver is triggered by the LED ? It should not be sensitive to the LED's light. If you move the LED to the other end of the breadboard, does it still happen ? Another thing: feedback through the supply, try decoupling the supply of the receiver with a 10 uF capacitor.

Comment: @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie The led is not an infrared led. Secondly I just tested it with an arduino, connecting pin 1 to a digital pin. The arduino reads random Ir signals. I guess it is not the led. Btw I'm powering it with the arduino's 5v source.

Comment: I was not suggesting it was an Infrared LED, otherwise you could not see it light up, unless you can see infrared ;-) (I can't). I thought that maybe the receiver is sensitive to light other than IR. It probably has an IR filter so it should not be sensitive to non-IR. If you completely shield the receiver from any light, do you still get random data ?

Comment: @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie I completely shielded the ir receiver and the arduino still reads random data from it. I also tested it with other TSOP38238's and same thing happens. Also I myself just tested it is not the arduino that is causing it since i don't get any data when I disconnect the receiver.

Comment: Then obviously the receiver is triggering on internal noise like Andy Aka suggests. This is strange, I have not seen this behaviour with several other IR receivers.

Comment: Can you show us your schematic? And upload the image somewhere (such as in this question) we can actually see it?

Comment: @user2235460 Quick check: Do you have any CFL lamps operating in the vicinity? My benchtop magnifier uses a CFL tube, which emits an IR signal at almost exactly 38 KHz. I have seen the effect you describe when using TSOP1738 sensors, which are very similar to your device.

Comment: @Anindo_Ghosh Good point. My indoor environment is lightened by CFL Lamps which may probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: @user2235460  The link to the image in the question is broken.  If you could fix it please, then I'll be able to reopen the question.

Comment: Sounds like it needs a filter so ambient light doesn't get to it.

Comment: My script tried to fix the broken image, but didn't notice it's still broken. I can't find a replacement, I'm sorry ...

Answer (score 1):

If you tune a cheap AM transistor radio to an unused channel you get noise coming out of the speaker because, in the absence of a proper radio transmission, the cheap automatic gain control just keeps raising its amplification and boosts the noise until it is at the same sort of level as it would expect for a proper incoming signal.

Do you see the comparison with what you have?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon for there to be random outputs coming out of an IR receiver. I have worked with many models of receivers in various types of packages and have seen this often. Some models will exhibit this problem to a greater or lesser degree.

The reason this happens is that there are actually bursts of light in our environment that are IR light. A lot depends on the type of lighting in an area. If the bursts happen to have frequencies and rise/fall times that match the bandwidth of the receiver part then there is possibility to see the receiver detect these bursts and output the "noise".

If you look at the transmission protocol of a typical IR remote control you will notice that they always include some type of leadin pulse or pulse sequence that has a defined timing characteristic. Successful use of an IR receiver requires that the protocol decoder detect this pulse sequence to know that an actual transmission is in progress rather than random noise.

Comment: @Michael_karas I know that there is infrared light around me but isn't the ir receiver supposed to filter out and take in only the 38khz modulated light?

Comment: Of course that is the intent of the IR receiver but it cannot be perfectly selective for a real application where the IR frequency and pulse widths will vary due to component tolerances, temperature and multipath light reflections in the room. That is unless you wanted to design and use an IR receiver that cost several hundred dollars.

Comment: You have to take me at my word and experience that low cost IR receivers will let through some environmental noise as their internal AGC cranks the gain up. I am sure that manufacturers have made improvements in the designs of IR receivers in more recent years but the fact remains that it is a competitive market and the component cost is generally kept as low as possible in exchange for a simpler receiver circuit and software in the decoder being able to discriminate between noise and legitimate IR transmission protocol.

Comment: @Michael_Karas In that case I'll just have to put up with it then. :-|

Comment: Exactly. If you make a reliable decoder you should have no problems at all. Do note that to make a robust decoder I have found it best to measure each and every pos to neg and then neg to pos edge of the output from the receiver. Then margin all the pulses against a fairly wide tolerance of nominal width. I've even used tolerances up to +/- 20 to 30% depending upon just what protocol is in use by the remote control. Doing so will allow you to get reliable transmission detections from greater range, more variance in lighting conditions and so forth.